# Is there a way to use rsync to copy only what has changed

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, rsync, backup

Im having a hard time with rsync to make an incremntal backup of a directory and upload it to a remote server, I have easily done this using  a full backup the hard part is with incremental is that how can I make a script to for example

```
rsync copy folder ( week1) ----> to remote server ---> /backup/$date/VM1
rsync copy folder ( week2) ----> to remote  server ---> /backup/$date/VM1
rsync copy folder ( week3) ----> to remote  server---> /backup/$date/VM1
```

but to only copy what has changed is this even possible to do using rsync and if yes how

Comment: How do you currently run `rsync`? Using the utility with e.g. its `--archive` option will usually be enough to make it skip already up-to-date data (provided that this data was also copied with `--archive` so that timestamps etc. is correct in the backup).

Comment: I'm also noticing that you have `$date` in the source path of the backup. Is that changing every week? If so, did you investigate how to use `--link-dest`? This is not an answer as I can't see how you're running `rsync` (see previous comment) and you never actually say what happens when you run your current workflow.